# add alias/cname for www in aws route53 for IIS website

Tags: iis, dns-zone, amazon-route53

I was using hosting with plesk panel until now, 
in plesk there would be a CNAME DNS record for the `www` record like this:

```
HOST             | Record Type | Value 
www.example.com. | CNAME       | example.com.
```

now in aws route 53, looking at docs and video tutorials I found 2 ways, one is to add 2 `A` records both pointing to the same `IP` of the webserver

and another way is to add 1 `A` record, and another `A` record as `Alias` for the first one

using both ways it will work depending on the `hostname` value in the `IIS`

so if the `hostaname` in `IIS` is set to `www.example.com` than only this url will work but the `http://example.com` won't work and if the `hostname` is `example.com` than the url with `www` won't work

my question is, what is the correct way to do this using `route53`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the options mentioned in the question will work.

What you did before will work on Route53:

```
example.com. A 192.0.2.1
www.example.com. CNAME example.com.
```

Or:

```
example.com. A 192.0.2.1
www.example.com. A 192.0.2.1
```

Or:

```
example.com. A 192.0.2.1
www.example.com. A <Route53 alias to example.com.>
```

On the IIS side, you'll need to add bindings for both `example.com` and `www.example.com` to the site. (It may be a good idea to set up an HTTP redirect from one of these to the other.)